# How to show twitter bootstrap modal via JS request in rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, modal-dialog

I want to show a twitter bootstrap modal as a response to a JS request. My show.js.erb function looks something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#dialog').modal('show')

});
```

Here "dialog" is the modal's id. The modal code itself looks something like this:

```
<div id="dialog" class="modal hide fade">
    <div class="modal-header">
          <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
          <h3> Showing Modal </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        I need to show up!
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn primary">Done</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

One thing I am sure of is that the javascript is being called. I can have it alter items on the page. Another thing is that modal is working fine. It shows up just fine when I use an HTML button to trigger the request like this:

```
<button data-controls-modal="dialog" data-backdrop="true" data-keyboard="true" class="btn danger"> Show </button>
```

Any idea why the modal doesn't show up on JS request?

Thank You!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I had a similar problem, which I solved with a slight twist

My modal div is rendered on the calling page (from a partial) and not by the response of the JS request:

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="modal-window">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <a href="#" class="close">×</a>
    <h3>Loading...</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body center">
      <%= image_tag "loading.gif" %>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

I use this link to rely on rails and Twitter unobtrusive JS:

```
<%= link_to negotiation.name, negotiation_path(negotiation), {:remote => true, 'data-controls-modal' =>  "modal-window", 'data-backdrop' => true, 'data-keyboard' => true} %>
```

and my show.js.erb looks like this (shortened)

```
$('.modal-body').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'negotiationdetail', :object => @negotiation) %>');
$('.modal-header').remove(); // don't need a header here
```

This works fine and has the benefit of showing a "loading" animation to the user while the modal is being populated.

Comment: With Bootstrap2, this link_to worked for me:  <%= link_to @country.name, country_path(@country), {:remote => true, 'data-toggle' => 'modal', 'data-target' => "#modal-window", 'data-backdrop' => true, 'data-keyboard' => true} %>

Comment: nice work gents.  Minor point: 'data-keyboard' and 'data-backdrop' are true by default in 2.0, so not really needed unless setting = false.

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked for me, too.
In rails 3 with bootstrap 2, link_to can be written as: <%= link_to negotiation.name, negotiation_path(negotiation), :class => :btn, :data => { :toggle => :modal, :remote => true, :target => "modal-window" } %>

Comment: Can anybody confirm that the above solution also works with Rails 4 and Bootstrap 3? Because for me it doesn't.

Comment: Remove all "hide" class references from you <div> if you use Bootstrap 3 instead of 2.

Comment: This may be obvious to most, but for us noobs out here, the show.js.erb file should be saved in the views folder and not in the assets folder.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem  and i fixed it by changing the javascript rendering to:

```
    $("#modal-window").find(".modal-content").html("<%= j (render 'new') %>");
    $("#modal-window").modal();
```

And the modal window to:

```html
    <div id="modal-window" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

You can check more detailed explanation here https://kolosek.com/rails-creating-modals

Answer (score 0):

That code looks like it should work (I'm doing something similar where I show the modal on document ready).

Check that you're loading the bootstrap-modal.js and make sure it's loading before your custom JS loads. If your custom JS is loading first, you'll see this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I have face the same problem and it has been solved as

1. load the jquery files (for example jquery_171_min.js)
2. and then load the less js and css and
3. load the bootstrap-modal.js

try with this sequence.. Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

This example works very well.

```
<body>
    <div id="top"> 
       <a tabindex="-1" href="metadata.html" id="metadata-link" data-target="#modal" data-toggle="modal">Metadata</a>
    </div>

    <div id="modal" class="modal hide fade in" style="display:none;">
      <div class="modal-header">header<a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</a></div>
      <div class="modal-body"></div>
      <div class="model-footer">footer</div>
    </div>

 <script>

  $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#top').find('a').trigger('click');

    });
 </script>
</body>
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem,

the cause for me was setting the modal wholly in partial file and put the trigger (button / link) calling the modal from other view file.

So let say that the trigger button is in my index view page and I construct the modal in _form.html.erb file; And I want to create a new record from index page using that modal.

Solution:

- create the outermost div which has the "id" in the same file as the trigger

**index.html.erb - trigger button**

```
<h3>
  <%= link_to 'Add Category',
    new_todo_path,
    remote: true,
    class: "btn btn-lg btn-success",
    data: {toggle: "modal", target: "#modal_form_category"} 
  %>
</h3>
```

**index.html.erb - outermost of the modal**

```
<div id="modal_form_category" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
</div>
```

new.js.erb

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#modal_form_category").html("<%= j render "form" %>");
});
```

P.S: pardon the new.js.erb I have no absolute reason enclosing the code untill the page is ready. I guess it will work even without the ready function; if you know is it necessary or not please do tell me.

Answer (score -5):

I am not aware of a jquery "modal" function. It looks like you are trying to get the element#dialog to show up. You could simply do:

```
$("#dialog").show();
```

Or am I totally missing the question?

Comment: Thanks although I don't think this is the right answer. It may help to check the modal's brief documentation here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html