# Render Bootstrap modal from partial in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to clean up my code a bit by placing my modal code inside of a partial, however I am encountering problems when trying to call the modal.

I tried the solution provided by [How to show twitter bootstrap modal via JS request in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529420/how-to-show-twitter-bootstrap-modal-via-js-request-in-rails), but if I understand correctly I have to add code to a particular controller to display the modal. That would be fine however **I would like to display the modal regardless of the controller/view** it is in. Is this possible?

What I have (completely from the above question):

current link (views/static_pages)

```
<%= link_to "ModalTest", 'shared/testmodal', {:remote => true, 'data-toggle' => 'modal', 'data-target' => "testmodal" }%>
```

**show.js.erb**

```
$('.modal-body').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'shared/testmodal'%>');
$('.modal-header').remove();
```

previous attempt:

```
<%= link_to "ModalTest", render(:partial => 'shared/testmodal') %>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can include the modal contents you put in the partial, in any view you need or in your `application.html`, with:

```
<%= render "shared/testmodal" %>
```

And toggle it with:

```
<%= link_to "ModalTest", "#testModal", "data-toggle" => "modal" %>
```

Where `#testModal` is your modal `id`.

Comment: It worked for the given example, but I've got one question. As you said you wanted to "display the modal regardless of the controller", how did you do that part to load the instance variables from the right controller asynchronously?

Comment: I created the variable inline in the form itself