# How to call bootstrap modal with Javascript and pass variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, modal-dialog, jquery-events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How to pass values arguments to modal.show() function in twitter bootstrat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379624/how-to-pass-values-arguments-to-modal-show-function-in-twitter-bootstrat)

I have a simple Bootstrap modal from tutorial:

```
<div id="modal-custom-id" class="modal hide fade">
 <div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
  <h3>Modal header</h3>
  </div><div class="modal-body">
   <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
  <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

And I have a Leaflet marker, to which I add a custom click function:

```
marker.on('click', function(e) {
   ...
}
```

How to write a click function witch will call and show Bootstrap model and fill it with custom title and body?

Comment: This looks like a good answer! http://stackoverflow.com/a/8613375/1358004

Comment: or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379624/how-to-pass-values-arguments-to-modal-show-function-in-twitter-bootstrat

Answer (score 0):

you can navigate the DOM and change the values before showing the modal.
Using your example you may have something like:

```
marker.on('click', function(e) {
   $("#modal-custom-id .modal-header h3").html("New Title"):
   $("#modal-custom-id .modal-body p").html("New Body"):
   $("#modal-custom-id").modal("show");
}
```